# Wordpress' Newsletter plugin - Unable to register

Tags: wordpress, newsletter

Hello I've created a custom form in WP's Newsletter plugin and showed it on a pop-up plugin. the form shows but it seems I am unable to register for subscription. The modal closes upon submission so I cant know anything after submit. There's nothing listed on the subscribers list.

here's my custom newsletter form:

```
<div>
        <input class="subscribe email" type="email" name="ne" size="30" required placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div>
        <input class="subscribe name" type="text" name="nn" size="30" required placeholder="Full Name">
</div>
<div>
        <select class="subscribe guardian" name="np1" placeholder="Guardian">
                <option value="parent/guardian">Parent/Guardian</option>
                <option value="corporate visitor">Corporate Visitor</option>
                <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div>
        <input class="subscribe submit pop-up-btn" type="submit" value="KEEP ME IN THE LOOP!"/>
</div>
```

And I've called the shortcode:

```
<div class="popup-form">[newsletter_form form="1"]</div>
```

Comment: please add your whole code on this answer like javascript, css, PHP and ajax call so we can review it and get answer proper.